# Which one is asymptotically less ?$n^\varepsilon$ or $\lg(n)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algorithms, asymptotics

First of all let me give you the convention $\lg$ is the logarithm with base $2$.

Now, I'm studying from the book Cormen's Introduction to algorithm (3rd edition) book. In this book, at page 96, It is written that;

> $\lg(n)$ is asymptotically less than $n^\varepsilon$ for any positive constant $\varepsilon$.

But I have difficulty to understand this. First of all, I want to be sure with the meaning of "asymptotically less". I think its mean that, for large values of $n$ one of them always has less values than the other, right?

If I'm right, how could I understand that, $\lg(n)$ is asymptotically less than $n^\varepsilon$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f(n)$ is **asymptotically less then** $g(n)$ means $f(n)=o(g(n))$ (see the formal "little-oh" definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)). Related [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/471206). Basically it means that for every $\epsilon>0$ we have $\frac{\log (n)}{n^{\epsilon}}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Asymptotic Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis), $f\sim g$ means $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=1$, and $f\lesssim g$ means $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\le1$. Thus, asymptotically less than would mean
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\lt1\tag{1}
$$
However, in [Algorithmic Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms), if
$$
0\lt c\le\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\le\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\le C\lt\infty
$$
for some constants $c$ and $C$, $f$ and $g$ are said to be of the same order.

So to be more precise, I believe you want it to be shown that $\log_2(n)=o\left(n^\varepsilon\right)$, which means
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log_2(n)}{n^\varepsilon}=0\tag{2}
$$
Since $(2)$ implies $(1)$, we will show that $(2)$ holds.

---

Since $1+x\le e^x$, we have $1+\log(x)\le x$. Therefore,
$$
\tfrac\varepsilon2\log(n)\lt n^{\varepsilon/2}
$$
thus,
$$
\frac{\log_2(n)}{n^\varepsilon}\lt\frac2{\varepsilon\log(2)}n^{-\varepsilon/2}
$$
Since the right side vanishes as $n\to\infty$, we get that $\log_2(n)=o\left(n^\varepsilon\right)$ for any $\varepsilon\gt0$.

Comment: thank you for your full explanation. But in your answer, I couldn't catch one point. Could you explain how you get **Since 1+x<=e^x we have 1+log(x)<=x** part?

Comment: substitute $x\mapsto\log(x)$

Comment: I think you meant ln(x) ? because e^(log(x)) is not equal to x ?

Comment: @robjohn In algorithm complexity theory they do not care for the constants in front, so everything which is "big-Theta" is considered to be asymptotically equal, so asymptotically less would be $o(g(n))$.

Comment: usually, in math texts, $\log$ means $\log_e$, not $\log_{10}$.

Comment: @robjohn then thank you so much, I was thinking it is log10 :)

Comment: @A.G.: however, the formula I wrote would not be true without the constant. In any case, if something vanishes, a constant multiple of it vanishes also.

Comment: @robjohn I mean the definition in the first line. It gives asymptotically equal if the limit is not zero as $f(n)=n$ and $g(n)=2n$ are considered to have linear complexity, i.e. all $Cn$ are asymptotically equal, they do not care for $C$.

Comment: @A.G.: I have added a discussion of the terminology difference between asymptotic analysis and algorithmic analysis.

Comment: I've seen $f(n) \lesssim g(n)$ in several places, but I cannot find it in a book (hopefully, an established and standard one which is suitable as a reference) with definition. Do you know any?

Comment: @Orat: The most common meaning I've seen is "less than approximately". However, there is no universally accepted meaning, so it is best to define the intended meaning of this symbol where needed (as I do above).

Answer (score 1):

This means that for any given constant $\epsilon $ , you can always find constants, $n_0 >0$, $c > 0$  such that :

$lg(n) < c n^\epsilon $ for all $n\geq n_0$.

Comment: I assume you mean $\lg(n) < n^\epsilon$ rather than $\lg(n_0) < n_0^\epsilon$?

Comment: This is too weak for being asymptotically less. For example, $f(n)=n$ and $g(n)=n+\frac1n$ satisfy $f(n)<g(n)$ for all $n$, but asymtotically equivalent.

Comment: @AnchitVirmani You answer the specific question about what means to be asymptotically less, but it *does not mean* that what you claim, and I gave you a counterexample. A definition must generalize to any two functions.

Comment: @A.G. Thanks for pointing out. I changed the answer. Is it correct now ?

Comment: @AnchitVirmani What you have now is called asymtotically **less than or equal to** or "Big-Oh" notation. To get strictly less than it should be "little-oh" growth. You can see the explanation in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/471206) at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As usual: study the difference (from its derivative).

To compare which of $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ is greatest, you just have to study the sign of $h = f-g$. Now if $h(t)$ is monotonous (i.e. going always up, or always down) at least after some $t_0$, then you can predict the sign at infinity.

Comment: I'm a cs student, so I could not understand what do you mean? If possible could you explain it a bit more? Maybe by showing an example?

Comment: to compare which of f(t) and g(t) is greatest, you just have to study the sign of h =  f-g, right ?  now if h(t) is monotonous (i.e. going always up, or always down) at least after some t0, then you can predict the sign at infinity.

Comment: Please add the 2nd comment in your answer. Else it might get deleted as low-quality.

Comment: done.  $$$$$$$$$$